# Rails how to hide form after save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

this is the case:

#### models/product.rb

```
belongs_to :brand
```

#### models/brand.rb

```
has_many :products
```

#### controllers/products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController 
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @brands = Brand.all
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.save  
      redirect_to :show
    else
      render :new, format: :html
    end
  end    
end
```

On product create the user can add a brand name and if the user add a brand name on next time to create a product the form for the brand did not show again.

Someone please have a idea how to do something like that on rails?

Comment: Can you please update the question with the code for the form's controller/view?

Comment: rev3rse, sure. just a moment

Comment: You are already redirecting to the show action, have a different  view there? your problem is solved. One more thing I would do is pass the show action id of the product, so it can show the product that is created

Comment: Fixing code formatting

Answer (score 0):

That's something to add in your view.

Use a condition around your brand form :

```
form @product do |f|
  f.text_field :name


  if not @product.new_record?
    f.select_field :brand_id, @brands, :id
  end
end
```